# CI Hacking the routes

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

So, i have some problem.

I just want to create some website where visitor can interact with my site if they're registered.
Let say they've provided their username,email,password, blah..blah..blah...
And then after they provided their blah..blah..blah.. it will autologin (if their data is passed) to my site.
After they logged in my site, they must provided more data again, like they uploaded their profile picture, how they control their privacy in my site, like step by step registration.

I don't want they interact with my site, until they complete their registration.
How do i make every page in my site looks like registration page until they finished their registration.
It's not like i will give this kind of function right.

```
if(is_login()){
    if(is_registration_complete()){
        //you're free to go
    } else {
       // complete your registration first
    }
} else {
    //you're not logged in
}
```

In my every controller, if you know what I mean :)

How do I create this function globaly?
If their registration isn't complete, they will go to registration controller, in every routes.
If they complete their registration, they will go to the, yeah you know the default routes.

I'm so sorry if my English is bad, English isn't my native language, sorry for grammar mistakes :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is probably to create a library with your checking function and then to include it in the Constructor of the impacted ControllerS :

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

       public function __construct()
       {
            parent::__construct();
            // Load the lib here or Autoload
            $this->load->library('mylogincheckhelper');
            $this->mylogincheckhelper->is_complete();
       }
}
```

And then you do all the ckecks and routing in the Lib.

Comment: And what is inside the is_complete() method?
Is that possible to load view inside that method?
And not load another view again from blog controller?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is to create a custom controller by [extend the core CI_Controller](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html). Then you can have your page controllers extend from your custom controllers. By extending, you inherit the functions of the parent, as well as run the parent constructor (or run it if you override it), making them "globally available" to whoever extends it.

```
//extend the core controller
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    //override to provide additional functionality
    public function __construct(){

        //run the core controller
        parent::__construct();

        //then do your login and registration checks here
        //you can put code here, call another function or load a helper class
        //or better, redirect them to your registration page
    }
}

//your page's controller extending from your custom controller
class Page extends MY_Controller {

    //not overriding the constructor will execute the parent constructor
    //every page that extends your extended controller will inherit it's functions
    //and execute it's constructor

}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a view with your post-registering stuff and make them conditionally visible. and include the view in your templates.